# Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop does not recognise Bluetooth

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth

I have Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop with Broadcomm Wireless.

After installing Ubuntu 13.10, it did not detect WiFi or Bluetooth. After checking in the forums I was able to rectify the WiFi issue. Now the WiFi light glows, and able to connect to my WiFi router.
Steps Taken :
1. Installed Synaptic.
2. Uninstalled bcmwl-kernel-source package( I had reinstalled this earlier, but my Wireless was not working,so tried this and next step)
3. Installed firmware-b43-installer and b43cutter.
4. Rebooted and the WiFi was working. But Bluetooth light is not on, nor does it identifies in rfkill

```
RFKILL command result:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When checking Bluetooth icon in System settings, it says "Drivers not installed"

```
my system settings using lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
02:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
02:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
02:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
02:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g (rev 01)
```

Rg,
Pram

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

I have a dual boot with Windows 7. Checked in the forums with suggestion of reinstalling Bluetooth Drivers. Went to Broadcom's site and installed latest Bluetooth Drivers.

Restarted to Windows 7, for the drivers to take effect.

Checked in Ubuntu again and Voila! Bluetooth started working again.

The Windows driver might have included firmware upgrades/patches that fixed the issue.